# textarea element from form opend with fancybox will not clear value

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox

I have a form `obs_form.php` witch is loaded through fancybox. This form has the role of adding or edit observations. This is accomplished with a `textarea`.

```
echo '<textarea id="obs" name="obs" autocomplete=off rows="0" cols="0">'.$row['obs'].'</textarea>';
```

The form and its functionality works perfectly in Firefox.
The problem comes from IE: let's assume that we have put a comment in the DB and after save (the info goes is stored in the DB) we realize that we need to do some modifications to the comment. We click the edit button we do the modifications to the comment and we save the info to the DB.
All good until now ... but if we want to do some other modifications to the text bad luck. Because the text area displays the original text (I think from cash) and not the one that we have saved last time....

I've tried to put on top of `obs_form.php` the fallowing script so that the value of textarea to be null and to force read it from the DB:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      document.getElementById("obs").value = '';
      return false;
   });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work ... where am I doing it wrong?

the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#obs").text('');
   return false;
  });
</script>
<?php //-------------------------------------------------------------- adauga Observatie
include 'mysql_conect.php';
    $page=$_REQUEST['page'];
    $proiect_id=$_REQUEST['proiect_id'];
    $azi=  strtotime ("today");
    $data=  date("Y-m-d",$azi);
    $task_id    = $_REQUEST["task_id"];
    $obs_id = $_REQUEST["obs_id"];

    $actiune="adauga";
        if ($_REQUEST["action"]=="editare") {
          $query=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM obs WHERE obs_id='.$obs_id) or die ("trrr");
          $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
          $actiune="editeaza";
        }
    echo '<div id=obsform>';
echo '<form name=obs id=obs method=post action=obs_editare_'.$page.'.php?action='.$actiune.' autocomplete="off">';
        echo '<input type=hidden name=task_id value='.$task_id.'>';
                    echo '<input type=hidden name=proiect_id value='.$proiect_id.'>';
                    echo '<input type=hidden name=obs_id value='.$obs_id.'>';
                    echo '<input type=hidden name=page value='.$page.'>';
                    echo '<input type=hidden name=data_obs readonly="readonly" value='.$data.'>';
        echo '<table border=0 cellpading=2 cellspacing=0 width=100%>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>';                        
                    echo '<label>Observatie</label>';
                    echo '<textarea id="obs" name="obs" autocomplete=off rows="0" cols="0">'.$row['obs'].'</textarea>';     
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'; 
                    echo '<label>User</label>';
                    echo '<input type=text name=user value="'.($row['user']).'">';      
                echo '</td>';                                               
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td colspan=2>';
                echo '<div class=form_diferentiator></div>';
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td colspan=2 style=text-align:center><input type=submit value='.$actiune.'></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
                      echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: I guess its a problem with your server side code.

Comment: but the code works just fine in firefox ....

Comment: Is it done through ajax?

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J8AUC/ it works fine, also in IE. The error is somewhere else...

Comment: no it isn't done through ajax .. it is done through php and some script .... se above code .

Comment: Did you validate your HTML? It looks suspiciously wrong, especially the parts where you don’t have quotes around your style attributes.

Comment: is there a possibility that the strange behavior to be from fancybox ?

Comment: it is from fancybox ... if i remove the triger that opens the form in the popup of fancybox the form displays corectly the info from the DB .... now what is the solutions for that ?

Answer (score 2):

textarea values are in the tag and not in value attribute!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   document.getElementById("obs").innerHTML = '';
   return false;
});
```

a better way is the .val() method of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#obs").val();
});
```

Comment: post your generated html with js

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the `value` attribute works also for textareas: http://jsfiddle.net/vvnAL/. Also, if you want to clear using jQuery, you need to pass an empty string `val('')`.

Comment: see above in my question I've paste the hole document

Comment: I've put the RAW document see above;
from `the code:` begins the paste

Comment: your code cannot work.... on the "echo <td>" above Observatie have no opening tag!

Comment: the problem is... your FORM have the SAME domid like your textarea!

Comment: when i formatted to look like a code I've accidentally deleted the `'`. again in firefox the code works just fine ....

Answer (score 0):

You might need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#obs").text('');
      return false;
   });
</script>
```